# Paypal Advanced Recurring billing with Express Checkout and Credit card payment using hosted pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, payment-gateway

In my application, I need to set recurring billing section using  paypal advanced and I am using the payflow section to do the same. I need both Pay with PayPal button process (Express Checkout process) and Credit card payment to create the recurring profile. My initial request is like this:

```
public static PayPalRedirectAdv PayFlow()
{

    NameValueCollection requestArray = new NameValueCollection()
    {

        {"PARTNER", "PayPal"},             // You'll want to change these 4
        {"VENDOR", "merchantname"},           // To use your own credentials
        {"USER", "username"},
        {"PWD", "abcdenfg"},
        {"TRXTYPE", "A"},
        {"AMT", "1.00"},
        {"CURRENCY", "USD"},
        {"CREATESECURETOKEN", "Y"},
        {"SECURETOKENID", "tokenId generated"},  
        {"RETURNURL", UrlReturn}, 
        {"CANCELURL", UrlCancel},
        {"ERRORURL", lUrlError},
        {"BILLINGTYPE","RecurringBilling"}

    };

    NameValueCollection resp = run_payflow_call(requestArray); // Will call the payflow end point via HttpWebRequest
    if (resp["RESULT"] == "0")
    {
        string mode = "TEST";
        return new PayPalRedirectAdv
        {
            Url = "https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=" + resp["SECURETOKEN"] + "&SECURETOKENID=" + resp["SECURETOKENID"] + "&MODE=" + mode
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new PayPalRedirectAdv { Url = string.Empty };
    }
}
```

Once the process is completed, I have set the url to an IFrame and it is embedded in one of my views in my mvc project. When the IFrame is loaded, it has two issues.

1) The page is redirected to the top level.  This means that the browser window is redirected to IFrame url. I have chosen Layout C as my hosted checkout page. When I use credentials supplied in the demo project, the browser navigation is solved; i.e Iframe correctly loaded in my view. 
Is there any setting in the Paypal manager settings to prevent this? I tried to fix this by sandboxing top level navigation, but this won't allow me to redirect to paypal site by clicking the "Check out with Paypal" button.

2) For a payment with a Credit card, once the transaction is successful, I will convert the existing transaction to a profile by:

```
    "TRXTYPE=R&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=Acme&USER=Acme&PWD=a1b2c3d4&ACTION=A&PROFILENAME=RegularSubscription&ORIGID=<PNREF>&START=12012002&PAYPERIOD=
WEEK&TERM=12&OPTIONALTRX=S&OPTIONALTRXAMT=2.00&COMMENT1=First-time
customer&AMT=42.00"
```

This works fine  and the recurring profile is created.

However, when I click on the "Check out with Paypal" button, this will take me to the Paypal page where I could login to Paypal using my Paypal credentials and then when I click the "paynow" button, it will deduct money from my account. This also has an PNERF value and when I used the same code above to convert the transaction to recurring profile by replacing Tender as P, but it shows me a response message that "the transaction id corresponding to this id is not found". The Paypal checkout process doesn't show any information about the user is going for a reccuring payment section.

Also, I followed [Express Checkout with recurring billing](https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/express-checkout-recurring-billing-payflow) to do the task, but I got BAID as null in the DoExpressCheckout step.

I need both pay with paypal and pay with credit options on my site, so what parameters should I use to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll just tell you what I did, because I'm not quite following what you're saying.  I created a website and a web app for a client, and the user registered on the website, paid with PayPal recurring payment.  PayPal's servers sent an IPN (Instant Payment Notification) back to my listener URL hosted on the website.  The code behind on this listener URL (Listener.aspx.cs) took care of extracting the data from the PayPal response including name, email, address, etc.  My code then created a user based on that information and inserted to the database.

Comment: Now, given what I've said, I'm not quite sure I understand your question.

Comment: If you'd like specific step by step instructions on how I did this, I'll be happy to do that - just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

```
string strUsername = "<<paypal_username>>";
    string strPassword = "<<paypal_password>>";
    string strSignature = "<<paypal_signature>>";
    string strCredentials = "USER=" + strUsername + "&PWD=" + strPassword + "&SIGNATURE=" + strSignature;

    string strNVPSandboxServer = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
    string strAPIVersion = "2.3";
    //4456193676582624                                                                   4025609244685781
    string strNVP = strCredentials + "&METHOD=DoDirectPayment" +
        "&CREDITCARDTYPE=VISA" +
         "&ACCT=<<CARDNO>>" +
         "&EXPDATE=<<EXPDATE>>" +
         "&CVV2=<<CVV>" +
         "&AMT=<<AMOUNT>>" +
         "&FIRSTNAME=<<CUST_NAME>>" +
         "&LASTNAME=<<CUST_LASTNAME>>" +
         "&CURRENCYCODE=<<CURRENCY_CODE>>" +
         "&IPADDRESS=<<USER_IP>>" +
         "&STREET=<<ADDRESS>>" +
         "&CITY=<<CITY>>" +
         "&STATE=<<STATE>>" +
         "&COUNTRY=<<COUNTRY>>" +
         "&ZIP=<<XIPCODE>>" +
         "&COUNTRYCODE=<<COUNTRY>>" +
         "&PAYMENTACTION=SALE" +
         "&L_NAME0=item1&L_DESC0=test1description&L_AMT0=1&L_QTY0=1" +
         "&L_NAME1=item2&L_DESC1=test2description&L_AMT1=2&L_QTY1=2" +
         "&L_NAME2=item3&L_DESC2=test3description&L_AMT2=3&L_QTY2=3" +
         "&VERSION=" + strAPIVersion;
    //strNVP = Server.UrlEncode(strNVP);
    try
    {
        //Create web request and web response objects, make sure you using the correct server (sandbox/live)
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strNVPSandboxServer);
        wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(strNVP);
        requestWriter.Close();

        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        //and read the response
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        string result = Server.UrlDecode(responseData);

        string[] arrResult = result.Split('&');
        Hashtable htResponse = new Hashtable();
        string[] responseItemArray;
        foreach (string responseItem in arrResult)
        {
            responseItemArray = responseItem.Split('=');
            htResponse.Add(responseItemArray[0], responseItemArray[1]);
        }

        string strAck = htResponse["ACK"].ToString();

        if (strAck == "Success" || strAck == "SuccessWithWarning")
        {
            string strAmt = htResponse["AMT"].ToString();
            string strCcy = htResponse["CURRENCYCODE"].ToString();
            string strTransactionID = htResponse["TRANSACTIONID"].ToString();
            //ordersDataSource.InsertParameters["TransactionID"].DefaultValue = strTransactionID;

            string strSuccess = "Thank you, your order for: $" + strAmt + " " + strCcy + " has been processed.";
            Response.Write(strSuccess);
            //successLabel.Text = strSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            string strErr = "Error: " + htResponse["L_LONGMESSAGE0"].ToString();
            string strErrcode = "Error code: " + htResponse["L_ERRORCODE0"].ToString();
            //errLabel.Text = strErr;
            //errcodeLabel.Text = strErrcode;
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something to catch the error, like write to a log file.
        Response.Write("error processing");
    }`enter code here`
```

try to use this code....no DLL needed to request for paypal payment.